# using hp 1050 c to print maps - Unicoe font FAIL

Tags: printing, unicode, autocad

i am using hp 1050 c to print a map from autocad 2007 , i have mutlipule lines of arabic and persian text on the map. the text are just fine in the dwg file but when printing the map, texts get inverse and mirrored (e.g. book --> koob i cant show the mirrored part :D ) do you guys know any solution for this? i have autocad 2007 on xp and all drivers installed. thnx

Comment: can any one of tell me what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: Arabic being written right-to-left surely has something to do with it.  How AutoCAD messes this up is best asked at the vendor's support forum.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with AutoCAD for years.  I have seen similar problems with other (high end HP) printers.  The fix was to switch from using the hppcl printer driver to using the postscript printer driver.  I do not know if a PS driver exists for your printer.  The best place to seek a better answer would be the [AutoCAD forums](http://forums.autodesk.com/)